# cmake g++-5: c++11 and OpenMP support

Tags: c++11, cmake, openmp

On a Mac pro I have installed g++

`brew install gcc --without-multilib`

I have then g++-5 installed in `/usr/local/bin`

The compiler supports OpenMP and also c++11

The following code compiles and runs as expected:

```
#include <iostream>     
int main(int argc, const char **argv)           
{                  
   auto i = 42;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for(int& e : arr) 
    {
          e = e*e;
    }
    #pragma omp parallel                     
    {                          
        std::cout << "Hello OpenMP!\n";         
    }                             
    return 0;                            
}
```

compiling:

```
g++-5 -fopenmp -std=c++11 omp_code.cpp -o omp_executable
```

However,

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-5 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-5 ..
```

tells me that `Could NOT find OpenMP (missing:  OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)`

and `The compiler /usr/local/bin/g++-5 has no C++11 support`

For OpenMP I use `FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP)` and for c++11 I use

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)                                        
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
  CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
```

Any idea how to solve this? A workaround was just to put the c++11 and `-fopenmp` flags even if the checks fail. That worked fine. However, I would like to have a better solution.

Comment: Did you scrape the build directory before running `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-5 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-5 ..` ?
This might be the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851830/cmake-doesnt-honour-d-cmake-cxx-compiler-g

Comment: yes. It seems this is it. It works now.

Comment: By the way, you can use `set_target_properties(sometarget PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11 CXX_EXTENSIONS FALSE CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)` to get a more robust check for C++11. Requires CMake 3.1+.